# distance from the bearing

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am learning mechanics. I am a little bit confused about the solution to the problem. It is an example in the book. A hiker walks 5 km on a bearing of 210 degree, then 8 km on a bearing of 290 degree. What is the distance and bearing of the hiker’s final position from her starting point? Give the distance to two significant figures and the bearing to the nearest degree.

The solution is based on the law of cosine I guess. I don't understand it. Maybe it is the way that the graph is modelled. The way I thought about it is if we set $z_1 = (5\cos(210),5\sin(210))$ and $z_2 = (8\cos(290),8\sin(290))$. Compute $z_1 + z_2$ and compute the angle using $\tan$. I don't understand why this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wrong answer because bearings are measured clockwise from north, while angles used in trigonometric calculations are usually measured anticlockwise from the positive x-direction, which on a map is east. Your idea with finding the vectors and adding them is completely correct, you just need to measure the angles correctly. The correct angle for your first bearing, for example, should be $-210° + 90° = -120° = 240°$, and your second angle should be $-290° + 90° = -200° = 160°$. If the answers still don't agree, it may be that the question is using relative bearings, but I think that's unlikely.

Comment: Hello. I agree with you in regards to this logic. In their solution this is seem to be what is happening, though I am getting different angles. I have attached a picture of the setup of the solution of the problem.

Comment: I have attached the picture. I don't understand the set up though.

Comment: The vector that they have marked a is that vector $(5\cos(240°), 5\sin(240°))$. The vector marked b is $(8\cos(160°), 8\sin(160°))$. The magnitude of the sum of these vectors is the distance, and the angle from the positive x direction will be given by $180° + \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$. You can then calculate the bearing from that. The extra $180°$ is necessary to put $(x,y)$ in the correct quadrant (as arctan cannot distinguish between $\frac{y}{x}$ and $\frac{-y}{-x}$, which correspond to different points in the plane).

Answer (score 0):

> The way I thought about it is if we set $z_1 = \pmatrix{5\cos(210^\circ)\\5\sin(210^\circ)}$ and $z_2 = \pmatrix{8\cos(290^\circ)\\8\sin(290^\circ)}.$ Compute $z_1 + z_2$ and compute the angle using $\tan$.

The formula $\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta}$ applies when  the angle $\theta$ is measured **anticlockwise** from the positive $x$-axis (which you can think of as the **east**), like so:

[image]

> [image]
>
> The solution is based on the law of cosine I guess. I don't understand it.

On the other hand, bearings specify angles **clockwise** from the **north**.

(The other thing about bearings is that they are always specified with three digits before the decimal point: so, $031.477^{\circ}$  instead of $31.477^{\circ}.)$